# React-Native Navigation bottom tabs for all required screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, navigationbar

I am working on the bottom navigation bar. I am following this documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-bottom-tab-navigator.html

It works well, I have 3 different tabs: `Feed`, `Messages` and `Profile`.
But from my `Feed` screen it leads to other screens such as `Post`.

Problem: When I am on a `Feed` screen and click on the `Post` I am getting redirected to a new page (do display post) but it has no Bottom bar included. Please note, that I don't want to include `Post` as a Tab. I want to have 3 Tabs: `[Feed, Messages, Profile]` but when `Post` is loaded navigation bar has to be visible. How do I achieve that?

Update:

Feed has a list of pots and when the post is clicked then I invoke: `this.props.navigation.navigate('Post`') to load a new page.

Flow definition:

- [Home] - Home screen
- [Message] - Message screen
- [Profile] - Profile screen
- [Post] - Post screen
- [NavBar] - Nav bar includes 3 buttons which will lead to -> 3 different screens - *Feed*,*Message*, *Profile*

Flow:

- [Home] contains [Navbar]
- [Home] leads to -> [Feed] via navbar
- [Home] leads to -> [Message] via navbar
- [Home] leads to -> [Profile] via navbar
- [Feed] leads to -> [Post] via regular onPress()
- [Post] contains [Navbar]
- [Post] leads to -> [Feed] via navbar
- [Post] leads to -> [Message] via navbar
- [Post] leads to -> [Profile] via navbar

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, StyleSheet, AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';

import { createSwitchNavigator, createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import OtherScreen from "./screens/OtherScreen";
import Feed from "./screens/post/Feed";
import SignInUpGender from "./screens/registration/SignInUpGender";
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs";

const MaterialBottomTabNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Screen1: Feed,
        Screen2: Messages,
        Screen3: Profile,
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Screen1',
        activeColor: '#f0edf6',
        inactiveColor: '#3e2465',
        barStyle: { backgroundColor: '#694fad' },
    }
);

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({
    Home: MaterialBottomTabNavigator,
    Other: OtherScreen
});
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
    SignInUp: {
        screen: SignInUpGender,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        }
    }
});

const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
        App: AppStack,
        Auth: AuthStack,
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
    });

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(switchNavigator);

const store = createStore(() => {});
class App extends React.Component{
    render (){
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <AppContainer/>
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: where you load your Post screen in your code above ?

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli Post is just loaded from the Feed, I am using this.props.navigation.navigate('Post') I am not sure how to structure alternatively. Please advice.

Comment: please include the flow that you want to have in a **text form** ... just pure explanantion ... I'm sure it'd help get the idea you want to achieve

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli thanks, I have updated my question.

Comment: @WildGoat did you found any luck in this?